# Bluetooth footswitch for Android video

Tags: android, smartphones, bluetooth, video-camera

I've got an LG V30 smartphone that I would like to start using to record my band's performances. The problem is that there are substantial times between each song (long story) so I would like to use a Bluetooth foot switch to turn on and off the stock video recording included in my smartphone camera.

What footswitch do I get with the software I need?

Comment: Hello there. I don't believe there's foot switches that work with bluetooth and control the shutter. You'll have to make one yourself. You can use a hand switch like this and modify it: https://www.ebay.ca/itm/Bluetooth-Selfie-Shutter-Remote-Camera-Control-Button-for-iPhone-6-7-8-Samsung/143425887540?hash=item2164d95d34:g:qSQAAOSwy21dt-8z  Any remote shutter like that one should start and stop the video. No need for any software.